# Formula Field Null in Test Method

Tags: apex, unit-test, formula-field

I have a formula field on campaign members that is simply `Contact.Account.Id`

I'm trying to get this value to populate in a test method, but it doesn't seem to be calculating. I know they are populated on read/query, but this doesn't seem to work for me. This still returns null:

```
    static testMethod void test(){
            //Create Account
            Account a = new Account(
                Name = 'Test'
            );
            insert a;

            //Create Contact
            Contact c = new Contact(
                LastName = 'Test',
                AccountId = a.Id
            );
            insert c;

            //Create Campaign
            Campaign ca = new Campaign(
                Name = 'Test',
                Class__c = 'Planning'
            );
            insert ca;

            //Create Campaign Member
            CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(
                CampaignId = ca.Id,
                ContactId = c.Id,
                Response_Date__c = Date.today()-1
            );
            insert cm;
            CampaignMember result1 = [SELECT Id,AccountID_Formula__c FROM CampaignMember];
            update cm;
            System.debug(cm.AccountID_Formula__c);
}
```

Any ideas on what my issue is here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are debugging wrong variable here .

Please try with below

```
System.debug(result1.AccountID_Formula__c);
```